# Lower withholding based on my calculations. How to get employer to change withheld amount?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, employment, withholding, form-w-4

My employer will withhold taxes from my paycheck as if I have been working at a particular salary range all year.  Basically: `pay period = (base salary / 2080 hours) * 80`, and taking all taxes as a percentage of that number.  This will equate to 37% withheld per paycheck.

I know how much I will make from them for the remainder of the year, and therefore I know the taxes I will owe on that amount.

The taxes on that amount, divided by the applicable pay periods of the year concludes that 26% of my paycheck should be withheld per period.

**How do I tell the employer exactly what amount to withhold?**

I will be able to make better use of the money now, rather than allowing the government to hold it interest-free for that amount of time. For instance, I could contribute the money to a Roth account in this tax year, instead of waiting for a refund next year.

Note: I do **not** have additional allowances to make on a W-4; I just know how much I will owe all authorities by using division.

Note: I have the capital to pay any possible misbalance when filing income taxes in March next year.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Employers withhold at rates specified in [Circular E](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p15.pdf) issued by the IR. You can request that 
additional money be withheld (not an issue here) or you can have 
reduced withholding by claiming additional allowances on a W-4 (i.e., 
more than just for you and spouse and dependents) if you believe that 
this will result in withholding that will more closely match the tax due. 
(Note added in edit):Page 2 of the W-4 form has worksheets that can
be used to figure out how many additional allowances to request.

Also, I wonder if your withholding will be 37% or final tax bill be 
26% of your adjusted gross income.  The tax brackets are the tax 
on *marginal* income. If
you are in the 28% tax bracket, you owe 28 cents in tax for each *additional* dollar of income, not 28 cents in tax for *every* dollar of income.  Your
overall tax might well be less than 20% of your income.  As a specific
example, in 2011 a married taxpayer filing jointly would be in the 
(highest) 35%
tax bracket if the taxable income was $379,150 or more (marginal tax rate
of 35% is applicable to every dollar more than $379,150) but the tax on 
$379,150 itself works out to be $102,574 or 27.05% of the taxable income.
So if you do expect to be earning around $350K or more in salary
between now and December 31 to hit that 26% that you expect you will
owe, you might want to consider paying a tax accountant for advice on how
to fill out your W-4 form for your new employer rather than relying
on an Internet forum such as this for free advice.

**Note added in edit:**  Your comment "... it is a cocktail
of ... federal taxes, state taxes, local taxes, health care
..." on the earlier version of my answer does raise the question
of whether you want your employer to withhold 26% instead of
37% and have the money go to meet *all* these obligations or just
26% towards your Federal income tax liability only.
The Federal W-4 form affects only how much money is withheld
from your paycheck and sent to the US Treasury.  Some of the
money that *each* of your employers withholds (Social Security and
Medicare taxes) is not affected by what you put down on 
the W-4 form.  Now, if you hold two jobs and the total income
shown on your W-2s is larger than the SS limit, you will 
have had too much Social Security
taxes withheld, and the excess will be a credit towards your
Federal income tax liability.  You have self-employment income
too on which you owe Social Security and Medicare taxes and you
are making estimated tax payments. The excess Social Security
tax payment can count towards this too (as well as income
tax on your Schedule C income).  Thus, if your new employer is
withholding too much, *you might be able to skip making the
fourth quarterly payment of estimated tax* or make a reduced
payment (there is no requirement that the four installments 
must be equal).  In short, there are lots of ramifications
that you need to take into account before deciding that
26% is the right number. Instead of filling out a W-4 
all by yourself right away, I strongly recommend 
reading up a lot on income taxes, or play with a tax
preparation program (last year's version will do a
pretty good job of at least getting you in the right
ballpark), or consult with a tax accountant.

Comment: Thank you dilip, although this has nothing to do with the marginal income tax rate. It is a cocktail of properly computed federal taxes, state taxes, local taxes and health care. when I do my taxes next year I will factor in investments and the another portion of my earnings subject to self employment tax - and as such I already am obligated to estimate my taxes. `the amount I will earn from this employer` is the only one in question, as they will simply be withholding the improper amount.

Comment: my real question then is: I didn't realize you can claim more allowances on the W-4 if you aren't actually the things the W-4 asks (ie head of household, married, dependents). Where on the form do I just write my custom allowance down after seeing that it will make my withholding more accurate?

Comment: @CQM See Page 2 of the W-4 form for how to proceed if you have multiple sources of income including spousal income, itemized deductions, etc.

Comment: The "brute force" method is to refer to the Circular E, find the withholding you want, in dollars, and submit for the number of allowances to get that withholding. Note - while a withholding allowance is equal to a dependent exemption, so is $3800 of mortgage interest, charitable donations, state income tax, etc.